# Where to save text files on Android for the user to access later

Tags: android, air

Where would I save text files that the user would be able to easily access later on Android?

I'm using Adobe AIR, which is an important note, and it has some predefined File paths:

```
var fileLocation:String = "my_file.txt";
file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(fileLocation);
file = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(fileLocation);
file = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(fileLocation);
file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(fileLocation);
file = File.userDirectory.resolvePath(fileLocation);
file = new File(fileLocation);
```

Note: There is a related question here [1] but it uses an Android specific API. It's fine if that's the best location but what that translates into for AIR is what I'm looking for (as in which is an equivalent location in the code above).

Let's say that one of those paths points to the appropriate or acceptable location. Would you place that file in a sub directory?

[1] [Android - Where to save text files to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581273/android-where-to-save-text-files-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File.userDirectory and File.documentsDirectory both save to the root directory of the SD card, this is probably the best starting point. You will probably want to add in another directory with the same name as your application to help the user find it though.