# Where should I choose to save text file in android?

Tags: android

I hope to export my data as a text file and save it to disk in Android, so I need to choose which folder I will save the file to.

I hope that a normal user can find the folder easily and the app does not need special permission to create the folder.

I have read some document, it seems that there are 3 ways: `Context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` and `Context.getExternalFilesDir(null)`.

You know some android users don't install SD card, so it seems that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` and `Context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` are be excluded.

Am I only to choose `Context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`? or is there a better way? Thanks!

BTW, From the document [Android - Where to save text files to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581273/android-where-to-save-text-files-to)

*Save it in internal phone storage, here no users and applications can access these files(unless if phone is rooted). But these files will be deleted one's the user selectes clear data from Settings -> Apps -> .*

It seems that normal users can't access the saved text files if I use Context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), is it right?

Comment: Environment.getExternalStoreDirectory() should point to a place where you can place files. On most phones without a real physical sdcard, they will still have some memory dedicated to "external storage" and expose a mountpoint like /storage/sdcard0/

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want a path that the user can modify and can have access

```
getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath();
```

More documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29).

EDIT:

This is how use in case error in some devices:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
String fname = "TEXT.txt";
File file = new File(path, fname);

if (!path.exists()) {
//noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
path.mkdir();
}

// YOUR CODE FOR COPY OR CREATE THE FILE TXT in PATH WITH THE VARIABLE file ABOVE
```

Comment: Thanks! Can etExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath() work if a user don't install SD card?

Comment: To  Santiago :  I get the error when I run your code.  java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS

Comment: @HelloCW I edited my answer, and yes, the code works for SDCARD and NO SDCARD installed because this get the default path for user save files, if user has SDCARD and the Android Version enable this path the file will save it, if not, use Internal Memory.